# Difference between using the new jQuery 1.6 $.animate "promise" and a callback?

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred

See here: http://blog.jquery.com/2011/05/03/jquery-16-released/

What is the difference between this new format:

```
$(".elements").fadeOut();

$.when( $(".elements") ).done(function( elements ) {
  // all elements faded out
});
```

and the old:

```
$(".elements").fadeOut(function() { /* all elements faded out */});
```

Comment: No promises but I might callback. :]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Chad said, $.when allows you to pass in a bunch of callbacks and once all of them have completed, done will fire.

http://vimeo.com/22687950 is a video on deferreds and about the 15 minute mark $.when() is introduced.  Arround 20 minutes you will see this code:

```
   var $balls = $(".bounceDemo"),
      a = $balls.eq(0).drop(500),
      b = $balls.eq(1).drop(2000),
      c = $balls.eq(2).drop(4000);
   $.when(a,b,c)
      .done(function(){
          //do something
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

The only difference that I know of is the $.when().done() syntax allows for multiple callback functions. Whereas many of the "old" methods of passing a callback function take 1 function object.

In your example I could have 5 different functions that are called on .done() instead of just the one callback on animation completion. You could even pass in an array of function objects with the $.when().done() syntax ([deferred.done()](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/)).

Answer (score 0):

The new format uses [deferred objects](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/). They were initially introduced as a more flexible alternative to traditional AJAX callbacks, as they provide higher-level control on callback chaining and resolution.

Deferred objects have proved useful enough that many people wanted to use them to chain animations into their AJAX application logic. Returning a [promise](http://api.jquery.com/promise/) from an `animate()` call was [possible but awkward](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5681411/new-jquery-api-to-allow-synchronous-operations-during-chaining) so far. jQuery 1.6 now supports it out of the box.